# proper session closing from Crystal enterprise server

Tags: java, crystal-reports

Can anyone tell the exact way to properly closing the session after login to the Crystal enterprise server?

Edit after the question was answered by Craig, May 4th, 2011:

- OK. `enterpriseSession.logoff()` works.
- Suppose I am not having the enterpriseSession object and I am having a `serializedSession` object with me.
- Is there any way to logoff using the `serializedSession` object am having instead of using `enterpriseSession.logoff()`?

Comment: Better add a comment under the answer if you need clarifications (rather than contacting Craig via the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnterpriseSession.Logoff

[SDK reference](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2SP2/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_dotNet_doc/doc/boesdk_net_doc/html/CrystalEnterpriseFrameworkLibrary44.html#2017965)